# Add graph to the First Panel in Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

We have an AmChart Stock Chart implementation with multiple panels. We want to add graphs with the `compared` property set to true on demand to the first panel of a Stock Chart containing multiple panels.

How do we do this?

What we tried so far:

We push data sets into an AmChart instance called tmpchart. When we add a chart to the panel below the first one it and then attempt to add a graph at index 1, the graph is not drawn. In case we do not have a graph in panel 2, the series are added to panel 1.

```
tmpchart.dataSets.push({
            //title: String(tmpchart.dataSets.length+1) + "th data set",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value" + intSegmentAdded,
                toField: "value" + intSegmentAdded
            }],
            dataProvider: newChartData,
            categoryField: "year",
            compared: true
        });

    console.log("---printing dataset -----")
    //console.log(tmpchart.dataSets);
    console.log(tmpchart.panels[0]);
    var oldPanel = tmpchart.panels[0];

    var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph.id = "g" + intSegmentAdded;
    graph.valueField = "value" + intSegmentAdded;
    graph.compareField = "value"  + intSegmentAdded;
    graph.comparable = true;

    graph.compareGraph = {type : "smoothedLine", fillAlphas : 0.15, lineThickness :2 };
    oldPanel.addStockGraph( graph );
```

[image: The current output]

As you can see in the output, the blue and yellow series are added first to the top panel and the green is added to panel below it. When we attempt to add another series to top panel - the red one - it does not appear, even though it is in the `dataSets` array.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears to be fine by itself. The only thing your sample is missing is a `validateData` call.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/14f27d8b5d465ce4f89279cb1188d2e2?editors=0010)

It might be helpful for you to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces your scenario more accurately so we can better understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would stick to the guidelines shared henceforth. I would check and revert back to you. Can you help me how to get an instance of Stockgraph in Panel 0, to hide / remove. I know the id - g1, g2, can I get instance using those.

Comment: You can use the panel's [getGraphById](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockPanel#getGraphById) method, e.g. `chart.panels[0].getGraphById('g1')`